# LoadBalancing Spring cloud data flow server

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

In spring cloud dataflow, as per my understanding each stream is a microservice but the dataflow server is not. Am I right?

Is it possible to have multiple instances of spring cloud dataflow(SCDF) server? How to loadbalance the dataflow server? I am planning to deploy it in AWS.The official documentation didn't mention anything about loadbalancing of dataflow server. If it is possible how do Dashboard, shell works?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SCDF-server is a regular Spring MVC + Spring Boot application that serves the REST-APIs, DSL commands, UI, and repository access for stream/task metadata persistence.

In platforms like Cloud Foundry, Kubernetes and others, upon scaling the SCDF-server, the platform automatically handles traffic routing and load-balancing.

If you were to orchestrate the deployment on your own and on AWS, you'd have to plug a load-balancer in front of the server instances. The shell, UI, and REST-APIs would hit the load-balancer instead, to interact with the SCDF-server.