# Running multiple SCDF(Local server not CF based) pointing to single DB for HA

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

We are using SCDF 1.2.3.RELEASE (Local Server) for calling different task created using spring cloud task 1.2.2.RELEASE. We want to run the multiple instances of SCDF in our environment so that we can achieve high availability and (Load Balancing).

want to confirm that when we trigger a task on one of the SCDF using its ReST API, is there any chance that both SCDF the instances may start running the task and create ambiguity because both SCDF will be pointing to same DB.

Unfortunately running SCDF on cloud like CF, Mesos or Kubernetes is not an option for us.

We tried running 2 SCDF pointing to the same DB and submitting task request. We did not get any error and task ran correctly as well. But maybe we were just lucky to NOT get an error. We want to be utterly sure that Execution ID being generated will not get executed at more than one SCDF server.

Comment: We have same requirement, did you achieve HA for local deployment?

Answer (score 0):

If a cloud runtime is not an option, you'd have plug a load-balancer in front of the multiple of SCDF-server instances. Check out this [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43438211/loadbalancing-spring-cloud-data-flow-server) or some more insights.

If you don't do this, each of the server instances will behave as an independent service and they won't be effectively load-balancing.

Comment: Yes we will add a load balancer in front of the multiple instances of SCDF, but want to confirm that when we trigger a task on one of the SCDF using its ReST API, is there any chance that both SCDF the instances may start running the same task and create ambiguity because both SCDF will be pointing to same DB.